# Android: Positioning buttons absolute (overlay other view)

Tags: android, button, overlay, android-relativelayout

I have an RelativeLayout and a couple of buttons.

The RelativeLayout  is a shape with a height of 600dp and width of 400dp (for example)
now i want to add buttons to that view.

The buttons need to overlap the RelativeLayout for about 50dp to the left.
a litle bit out of the view. is this possible and how?

Thank you!

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried creating an relativeLayout and added the buttons as follow:

Button bt1 = new Button(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,100);

params.setMargins(-50, 0, 0, 0);
relLayout.addView(bt1, params);